# How can I start Emacs with one process in the top window and another in the lower window of a frame?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23

I have some processes that run from functions, i.e.:
   M-x run-proc1
   M-x run-proc2

I would like to know what command to issue from the command line to run emacs with `run-proc1` running in the upper window and `run-proc2` running in the lower window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might get better answers later, but appending this to your ~/.emacs.d/init.el might work.

```
(split-window-vertically)
(run-proc1)
(other-window)
(run-proc2)
(other-window)
```

Alternatively (for another approach), see [this link](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html).

Comment: emacs -f split-window-vertically -f other-window -f run-proc1 -f other-window -f run-proc2                                                     thanks!

Comment: as for your original solution, I would like to do that as well.  however, how can I first set there to be only one window, so that I always end up with two?